# handling performance issues in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parallel-processing

I have billions of records to transmit via SSMS and looking at improving the migration speed. I am trying to save the resultset into a table. I am taking into account my front end would be slow since all that data would be in one table. I am basically looking at various options. So I am thinking of having multiple physical tables. I just need last 5 years of data. Will it be faster If I execute 5 different versions of the same stored procedures with different year filters and populate the tables . I know one can achieve parallelism in SSIS. My only fear is since all the five storedprocedures are running in parallel , will they lock down the tables

Comment: What do you mean "via SSMS?" SSIS and SSMS are different things - can you clarify - do you mean SSIS? Are you just copying a table over - do you really need a stored procedure to extract the data? How often do you need to transmit this data? Daily? Monthly? Hourly? Once off? Is the target database on the same server or a different server? Do you have to use SSIS (BCP native can be faster and simpler). What do you mean "my front end will be slow"? Are you saying that you understand that the front end application might have performance issues during the data transfer?

Comment: Hi Nick, Sorry for the confusion. It was bit late last night when I wrote. I meant SSIS. I know SSMS and SSIS are different :). I have already a SSIS package in place that is doing data migration on a weekly basis. Its scheduled via a Sql job. The source and target databases are on two different servers. What I meant of slowing down the application is not during migration process but after migration is over. If I dump the data in one single table, my front end would need to query this one table that has billions of records hence the thought of breaking down the  into multiple tables

Comment: If your application has a performance issue then you undertake performance tuning. That is: isolate which queries are the issue, then apply things like indexes, partitioning etc. to improve. Splitting one table into many is almost always the wrong thing to do. You can get a very similar effect by just creating a bunch of filtered indexes or implementing table partitioning. This makes the table split transparent to the end user.

Comment: If you use table partitioning then you can also load one partition at a time then just switch it in and again it becomes transparent.

Comment: So is the issue copying five years data once a week or is it possible application performance issues or is it both? Is the data coming from an identical table or are you transforming it in some way? Is it going to continue being copied once a week in future? Is the data ever back dated (i.e. records are altered historically, say 2 years ago)

Comment: Hi nick ,the queues have been already optimised , indexes applied etc. There are two issues that I am tackling. 1. Speeding up migration. 2. Storing the data in multiple tables so from UI perspective it can do smArt search. The migration would be running weekly.  I have seen articles on table partioning that improves SSIS performance . The only thing is I haven't done it before and looking for examples

Comment: The idea is I shall have 5 physical tables and data should be flushed based on last 5 years. So one table will store 20-6 related records the other 2015 related and so on and so forth

Comment: It's unnecessary to have separate physical tables if you implement partitioning. You're posing a complicated solution to a problem that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into table partitioning schemes in sql server. It seems like the Year column would be a good field to use in your partitioning function.

[Table Partitioning in SQL Server](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/partitioning-in-sql-server-part-2.html)

Comment: if i partition the main table based on year, how would i configure it in SSIS

Comment: I haven't done table partitions before. The periodendate field is datefield and need to extract the year from it as that's the filter. I need data for the last 5 years and each partion should contain a year . So there should be a table that stores on current year , a table that stores only 2016 year records etc . Can you help me create that partion

Comment: Google table partitioning. It's transparent to your application and to SSIS. You don't have to do anything special. That's the point - it's completely transparent. You don't have need to have any special code or allowance for it